# setting a textfield.text value

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm trying to edit a text field within a GUI created in xcode. How would I go about setting the text value of a text field with coding?

here is my attempt:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var value: UITextField!
 value.text = "hey"
```

Comment: ya dats right , what else you want ? In viewDidLoad method you just set the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    value.text = "hey"
}
```

**OR**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    value.text = "Your Text"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    value.text = "Your Text"
}
```